# consistent evaluation of input parameters

Tags: r

Thanks to R's evaluation of function arguments, it is possible to specify a consistent set of input parameters, and have the others automagically calculated.

Consider the following function, linking the concentration, mass, volume and molar weight for a dilution in chemistry,

```
concentration <- function(c = m / (M*V), m = c*M*V, V = m / (M*c), M = 417.84){

  cat(c("c=", c*1e6, "micro.mol/L\n",
          "m=", m*1e3, "mg\n",
          "M=", M, "g/mol\n",
          "V=", V*1e3, "mL\n"))
  ## mol/L, g, g/mol, L
 invisible(list(c=c, m=m, M=M, V=V))

}
```

Is there a way to specify only one of the equations and have R figure out the others by inversion? I realise this is limited to simple linear relationships, as the inversion cannot generally be expressed analytically.

```
concentration <- function(c = m / (M*V), m, V, M = 417.84){

 ## { magic.incantation }
 ## mol/L, g, g/mol, L
 invisible(list(c=c, m=m, M=M, V=V))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the BB package, and in particular the function BBsolve().  BBsolve does a Newton-Raphson backsolve of the equation(s) you feed it.   As it happens :-) , I wrote and published a function "ktsolve" which allows you to enter a set of equations and some subset of the variables, and it'll return the values of the other variables.  (It's named in honor of the commercial TK!Solver package).  If you want to  try it out, you can get it at http://witthoft.com/ktsolve.R  (or http://witthoft.com/rtools.html and click on the link there).

Comment: Baptiste: start w/ the BBsolve help page, then try the sample function in the ktsolve.R function header.  # yfunc -- is a function of the form:
#  yfunc<-function(x) {
#  y<-vector()
#  y[1]<-f1(x)
#  y[2]<-f2(x)
#  y[length(x)]<-fn(x)
#  y
#  }
#  where y[j] are dummies which will be driven to zero,
#  and x[j] is a dummy vector which will be filled in with 'guess'
# So, eqns in the form A=f(x) must be entered as  y[j] <- f(x)-A   
# Example:  d = a + sqrt(b) and a = sin(a/b) + g*exp(f*a)  become
#  y[1]<- a - d +sqrt(b)  and y[2]<- sin(a/b) +g*exp(f*a) -a ,

Comment: and...   # and e.g.
# known <- list(a=3,d=5,g=.1)  are the fixed parameters and
# guess <- list(b=1,f=1) are the initializers for BBsolve()